# Google Sheet to auto fill weekday dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I would like to create a Google Sheet whereby the dates of the data will change weekly, and showing only the Weekdays if possible.

For example:
This week the columns will show 11th Oct, 12th Oct, 13th Oct, 14th Oct and 15th Oct. Without human intervention, can the dates change after the week has passed? Meaning after Saturday, the data will change to 18th Oct, 19th Oct, 20th Oct, 21st Oct and 22nd Oct, so on and so forth.

I want to show the date is changing, not daily but weekly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Clear the five cells where you want these column headers to go. Then place the following formula in the first of those five cells:

`=SEQUENCE(1,5,2+"10/2/2021"+(INT((TODAY()-"10/2/2021")/7)*7))`

Then select the five cells and change the format like this:

**Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format >** *dd mmm*

The date of 10/2/2021 that appears in the formula is somewhat arbitrary. It just needed to be any Saturday in the past, so I chose that one.